# Как перевести меню на js?

Tags: javascript, css3, вёрстка

Cделал меню-слайдер на css3, но меня не устраивает как он работает. В данном виде бекграунд закреплен с помощью `fixed` (иначе как надо не выглядит), но из-за этого невозможна прокрутка. Понимаю, что нужно делать на js, но как ума не приложу, сам с js недавно.
Пример [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/12rnbxg0/9/) (в firefox не работает пока)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 16px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #ddd;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -330px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.nav:hover .link {
  width: 5%;
}

.nav .link {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: .5s width;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .link:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.nav .link:hover {
  width: 80%;
  color: #555;
}

.link1 {
  background: url('https://cdn.mashina.kg/tachka/images//a/2/3/a236caeb97c22a804cabc349d50630a2_1200x900.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link2 {
  background: url('http://www.avtovzglyad.ru/media/article/470fe986b4955ce9faf8b06818c79f841bd73c.jpg.740x555_q85_box-0%2C0%2C1024%2C768_crop_detail_upscale.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link3 {
  background: url('http://autodrop.ru/uploads/1353693314_mashina-v-kredit-bez-procentov.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link4 {
  background: url('https://static.riafan.ru/uploads/2018/01/16/orig-15161241775df3417dd73a6a5155fc7394f4497d24.jpeg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link5 {
  background: url('../img/Side-Profile-2016-BMW-X6-white.png') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link6 {
  background: url('https://www.conceptcarz.com/images/BMW/BMW-Limited-Edition-Individual-M6-manu-07_01.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link7 {
  background: url('https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ax9FhRp6CDA/WJZf8UNllfI/AAAAAAAACFQ/GmZyevgUmkQSBXD6catacpgw5CXaNZlNACLcB/s1600/3rabhard.com_1395505864_664.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='nav link1'>
  <div class='link'></div>
  <div class='link link2'></div>
  <div class='link link3'></div>
  <div class='link link4'></div>
  <div class='link link5'></div>
  <div class='link link6'></div>
  <div class='link link7'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если логику поведения реализовать не через `margin-left`, а через `flex-grow` `flex-srink` - тогда прокрутки, по идее не будет. Правда картинка, наверное исказится.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, с помощью `flex-box`, вполне прилично получилось, как по мне, . Нужно только настроить минимальную ширину и картинки.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 16px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.nav{
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.link {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  flex-grow: 8;
  transition: 1s;

}
.link:hover{
  width: 90%;
}

.link1 {
background: url('https://cdn.mashina.kg/tachka/images//a/2/3/a236caeb97c22a804cabc349d50630a2_1200x900.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
background-size: 600px;
  
}

.link2 {
  background: url('http://www.avtovzglyad.ru/media/article/470fe986b4955ce9faf8b06818c79f841bd73c.jpg.740x555_q85_box-0%2C0%2C1024%2C768_crop_detail_upscale.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link3 {
  background: url('http://autodrop.ru/uploads/1353693314_mashina-v-kredit-bez-procentov.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link4 {
  background: url('https://static.riafan.ru/uploads/2018/01/16/orig-15161241775df3417dd73a6a5155fc7394f4497d24.jpeg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}

.link5 {
  background: url('../img/Side-Profile-2016-BMW-X6-white.png') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}


.link6 {
  background: url('https://www.conceptcarz.com/images/BMW/BMW-Limited-Edition-Individual-M6-manu-07_01.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}


.link7 {
  background: url('https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ax9FhRp6CDA/WJZf8UNllfI/AAAAAAAACFQ/GmZyevgUmkQSBXD6catacpgw5CXaNZlNACLcB/s1600/3rabhard.com_1395505864_664.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='nav'>
  <div class='link link1'></div>
  <div class='link link2'></div>
  <div class='link link3'></div>
  <div class='link link4'></div>
  <div class='link link5'></div>
  <div class='link link6'></div>
  <div class='link link7'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант, хотя, я наверно не правильно выразился, проблема не в поведении вкладок, а в том, что фоновые картинки не двигаются вместе с менюшкой.

Comment: Не понял, как сделать тоже самое, но без fixed. 

Сделал по образу, только немного по другому 

https://jsfiddle.net/dhqhLugb/7/

Answer (score 0):

Признаться честно, `css` не самая сильная моя сторона и именно поэтому мне стало интересно  реализовать Ваш пример.

Сделать полностью адаптивным без `js`, как мне кажется нельзя. Есть проблема, когда картинки занимают меньше места чем растягивается `.accordion-item`. Замечу, это пример  без магии и в нем полностью отсутствуют `"вот тут чуть-чуть добавил, а вот здесь что-то ещё"`. Я старался сделать как можно проще.

Этот же пример можно переписать на `flex-basis`, тогда всю адаптацию можно будет в `js` и в `css` изменять лишь одно свойство.

Но в любом случаи нужно подгонять изображения. То есть начать стоит с расчетов размера самого `fccordion`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let accordion = document.querySelector('.accordion');
  accordion.addEventListener('click', ({
    target,
    currentTarget
  }) => {
    if (target.classList.contains('accordion-item')) {
      currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item').forEach(item => {
        item.dataset.activated = (item === target).toString();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  max-width: 698px;
  max-height: 199px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.accordion {
  --accordion-item--length: 5;
}

.accordion-item {
  background-image: url('http://2ykov18qyj81ii56523ib0ue.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/marvel-black-panther-blue.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-size: cover; */
  opacity: .5;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex .4s, opacity .3s;
}

.accordion-item[data-activated="true"] {
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  flex-grow: var(--accordion-item--length);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="true"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Прочитал про движение картинок... Вы об этом?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let accordion = document.querySelector('.accordion');
  accordion.addEventListener('click', ({
    target,
    currentTarget
  }) => {
    if (target.classList.contains('accordion-item')) {
      currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item').forEach(item => {
        item.dataset.activated = (item === target).toString();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  max-width: 698px;
  max-height: 199px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.accordion {
  --accordion-item--length: 5;
}

.accordion-item {
  background-image: url('http://2ykov18qyj81ii56523ib0ue.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/marvel-black-panther-blue.jpg');
  background-position: 0 center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-size: cover; */
  opacity: .5;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex .4s, opacity .3s;
}

.accordion-item[data-activated="true"] {
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  flex-grow: var(--accordion-item--length);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="true"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
    <div class="accordion-item" data-activated="false"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: я не против js, просто я в нем не силён.
Про движение картинок - к каждой вкладке прикрепляется отдельная картинка (по сути одна и та же, только разного цвета), все картинки накладываются друг на друга. И когда вы наводите на вкладку, то она раздвигается, создавая видимость перекрашивания всего меню.
Пока придумал только такой способ реализации.